# Using Mac OS guest in VMPlayer. Unable to connect to the Internet

Tags: networking, mac-osx, vmware-player

I am new to Mac OS. I am using VMPlayer on a Windows 7 machine to use Mac OS 10.4.1.

I am not able to connect to the Internet in my Guest OS - Mac. I tried both Wireless and LAN but nothing seems to work. Help appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy: Running MacOS inside a virtual machine is not legal, with the exception of running MacOS Server on Apple Hardware either in Parallels Server on MacOS or Parallels Server Bare Metal (and likely in VMWare Fusion). Apple does a lot to make it as difficult as possible to do what you are trying and it's possible that your network issue is a consequence of this.

Anyway, this is totally unsupported by both Apple and VMWare.

Comment: I see. In fact, I am very interested to buying one. The problem is that it is pretty costly, and I wanted to try this out before I buy.

Appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

depends on how your windows 7 machine is connected to the internet, IMHO the best choice would be to put your guest network interface in a NAT mode.
I can't remember if you can change this using the GUI of vmplayer but if not, it's just a parameter to change in the .vmx file. 
It's something like : ethernet0.connectionType= "nat" <-- that's what you would use to be sure your mac vm can access internet through your windows 7 host.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/vmware
.encoding = "windows-1252"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "4"
memsize = "1512"
ide0:0.present = "TRUE"
ide0:0.fileName = "tiger-x86.vmdk"
floppy0.startConnected = "FALSE"
floppy0.fileName = "A:"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.virtualDev = "es1371"
displayName = "tiger-x86"
guestOS = "other"

Comment: nvram = "tiger-x86.nvram"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ide0:0.redo = ""
uuid.location = "56 4d 69 c6 50 af 72 c7-9c e0 42 c8 89 46 dc 76"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 69 c6 50 af 72 c7-9c e0 42 c8 89 46 dc 76"
floppy0.fileType = "device"
ide0:0.mode = "persistent"
extendedConfigFile = "tiger-x86.vmxf"
floppy0.clientDevice = "FALSE"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
checkpoint.vmState = ""

Comment: replay.supported = "FALSE"
replay.filename = ""
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "16777216"
sound.autodetect = "True"
sound.fileName = "-1"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
numvcpus = "1"
scsi0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "nat"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "true"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "FALSE"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0c:29:46:dc:76"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
floppy0.autodetect = "TRUE"
ide1:0.present = "FALSE"
ide0:1.present = "FALSE"
parallel0.present = "FALSE"
ethernet0.linkStatePropagation.enable = "FALSE"